# mod_rewrite to get files from Amazon S3?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, amazon-s3

Is it possible to use mod_rewrite with Amazon S3 so that when a user types a url such as: www.example.com/link , It can retrieve/download the index.php file from a folder named "link" in S3?

For example:
www.example.com/user --> s3.amazonaws.com/mybuckname/user/index.php 
www.example.com/user/anotherfile.php --> s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/user/anotherfile.php

Essentially, I want www.example.com to equal (probably not the proper terminology) s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname

However, I also have files/folders on the EC2 server I use to host the actual "www.example.com", so I want to find a solution that will not create a conflict.

I'm terrible with regex, and I don't even know if this can be done so some help would be nice. If mod_rewrite isn't the way to go, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 won't run PHP code, at all, so nothing you do here is likely to work.

Comment: Also, why? What are you trying to accomplish here?